# How do I remove or replace non UTF-8 characters in a file?

Tags: rust

I have a CSV file which cannot simply be loaded by using the csv crate, as it complains about a handful of non UTF-8 characters. I want to either remove, or preferably replace the non UTF-8 characters with a '£' sign (which is what they were in the source system).

I decided the simplest way might be to read the file and convert the characters before treating it with the csv crate.

I am quite new to rust, but have managed to read the file into a Vec<u8> and now need to iterate through the file replacing or removing the three bytes which contain
11101111 10111101 10111101    wherever they occur in the relatively small file (5k).

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you removing one particular non-UTF8 byte sequence, as your last paragraph suggests, or *every* non-UTF8 byte sequence, as your first paragraph suggests?

Comment: The sequence you posted is valid utf8 for `'ｽ'` btw

Comment: Also, the `csv` crate can absolutely read files that are invalid UTF-8, so long as they are at least ASCII-ish. It's mentioned right in the "brief overview" section at the top of the docs. See also: https://docs.rs/csv/latest/csv/struct.Reader.html#method.byte_records

Comment: @gspr every occurence is to be removed or replaced

Comment: @cafce25 - yes, but the csv crate or maybe it is the serde crate complains it is non UTF-8.

Comment: Maybe you can try and create a [mre] that shows the error because as it is it's not reproducible for me.

Comment: @cafce25 Hi - probably best is to clone https://github.com/maxweld/csv-playpen.
cargo run rates.csv seems to work
cargo run Membership_Membership_133184309529992066.csv does not

Comment: `Membership_Membership_133184309529992066.csv` does indeed contain invalid UTF-8 characters but they are in fact valid ISO-8859-1 (the £ sign is encoded as hex A3). So it's just a matter of reading it with the correct encoding, instead of UTF-8.

Comment: @k314159 How do I read it with the correct encoding?

Comment: Again, it's not the csv crate that's complaining about UTF-8. It's the fact that you're using types (like `String`) that require the data to be valid UTF-8. To be clear, I'm the author of the csv crate and it is *specifically* designed to not require valid UTF-8. But if you request valid UTF-8---which is what you're doing---then invalid UTF-8 will indeed result in an error. You can even use Serde and still parse invalid UTF-8. See the last example here: https://docs.rs/csv/latest/csv/tutorial/index.html#serde-and-zero-allocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read the file containing ISO 8859-1 data into string records, you can transcode it to UTF-8 using the `encoding_rs` crate:

```
use encoding_rs::WINDOWS_1252; // ISO 8859-1
use encoding_rs_io::DecodeReaderBytesBuilder;

let file = DecodeReaderBytesBuilder::new()
    .encoding(Some(WINDOWS_1252))
    .build(std::fs::File::open(path).unwrap());
let mut csv_reader = csv::Reader::from_reader(file);
// ... use it ...
```